# How do I adjust the Tab Size in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I've created a tab and figured out how to change the color according to Ionic 4 CSS Docs found here
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables

But there is not reference there as to how to change the size, the code on for ionic 3 does not work.

here is what I have

```
ion-tabs {
margin-top: 80px;
--ion-tabbar-background-color: #FBFBFB;
--ion-tabbar-text-color-active: #87BCDE;
--ion-tabbar-text-color: #424242;
font-size: 40px;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

With below code you can change the size of tab-label :

```
ion-tab-button {        
        ion-label {  
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for color in variable.scss:

```
  --ion-tab-bar-background: var(--ion-color-primary);                    
  --ion-tab-bar-color: var(--ion-color-dark);    
  --ion-tab-bar-color-activated: var(--ion-color-light);
```

for size i think it's not ready yet to style like that.
you can change style of tab-selected in your global.sass

```
:root{
    .tab-selected{
        font-size: 32px !important;

        ion-icon{
            font-size: 32px !important
        }
    } 
}
```